# How to chain SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables: `series`, `seasons`, `episodes`, `images`. Each series consists of multiple seasons which consists of multiple episodes. Each episode has one or more images attached to it. Now I would like to retrieve one series including all its seasons, episodes and images.

```
SELECT * FROM series
LEFT JOIN seasons ON seasons.seasons_series_id=series.series_id
LEFT JOIN episodes ON episodes.episodes_seasons_id=seasons.seasons_id
LEFT JOIN images ON images.images_id=episodes.episodes_images_id
WHERE series.series_id=1
```

The above query does not work, because `seasons_id` is not available when running the second LEFT JOIN etc. Should I be using nested queries instead?

Comment: Why do you think it's not available...?  Please show sample data, table structure, and desired results.

Comment: look at your table structures to see which columns are available in it

Comment: Unless you have `series` that have `episodes` but do not have `seasons` (which seems like a data problem) I do not understand why your query wouldn't work given what you've shown so far.  Show your table schema, some sample data, the results you're getting, and the results that you expect to get.

Comment: The example is an abstraction to easier communicate what I'm trying to do. I've added the required columns.

Comment: Define *"does not work"*: error message? It would also be helpful if you provided sample data for each of the tables and the desired output for it.

Comment: seasons_id definitely **IS** available when running that second left join. Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: It almost sounds to me like you want a FULL OUTER JOIN (which MySQL does not support, AFAIK) instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @trincot I'm unable to retrieve the images. There is no real error, the images are just not part of the returned data. Also understand that above is an abstraction, posting the actual query would make it too complex to understand.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem with the info you have given. You will need to provide something we can reproduce the problem with.

Comment: @trincot From the below comments, it seems the above query should work. So I may have a problem on a different level.

Comment: My crystal ball is not working well today ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the query posted to the question, the `seasons_id` generally **IS** available for that second `LEFT JOIN` (and the third, if it comes to it).

When you add additional `JOIN`s to a query, those `JOIN`s take into account not only the table from the original `FROM` clause but also the entire result sets built up by any additional `JOIN` so far. This is one reason why *always* using an alias for your tables is a good idea... its possible to include the same table in a query more than once via a `JOIN`, and aliases can be important to keep straight separate instances of the same table.

The only case when your `seasons_id` would not be available is when you have a `series` record that does not have any `seasons` records associated with it. In this case, you would have a `NULL` value in your results for the `seasons_id`, and you would further have no way in the schema shown to connect any `episode` record with that `series` record at all. In this schema, every `series` must have at least one `season` if it is to have any `episodes` or `images`. Thus, the missing `seasons_id` wouldn't matter anyway, because you couldn't ever hope to match any `episode` records for that `series`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your query.. if a relationship breaks down and left join shows e.g. A season 2 with no known episodes, then there won't be any images for those non-episodes. It doesn't stop the series having two seasons, you just see results like:

```
Game of thrones, season 1, episode 1, image 1
Game of thrones, season 2, null, null
```

If your database enforces relationships then you'll never be able to insert images from game of thrones season 2 episode 1, because the episode has to exist first to be a parent to the child images. If your database doesn't enforce relationships, then you can go ahead and insert a load of images and give them all an episode ID of 971 which you predict is what s2 e1 will get when you do get around to insert it, but they won't show in your query because theyre orphans if episode with ID 971 doesn't exist in the DB yet

If you're hoping your query will show these orphaned images, you'll have to write it in a different way

Answer (score -1):

You might having missing columns as your are not using aliases for your tables, so MySQL does not know which column belongs to each table. Try to use an alias for every table and run it again.

Hope this helps